# Laravel yajra table pagination server side , empty on next page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I've a thousands records and feels slow when I was troubleshoot it cause pagination on yajra handled on frontend. so I've tried to improve my code.it was rendered fast but when I click to next page the table show me empty data.

here is my attempt :

```
$model = Order::with([
            'buyer',
            'order_details.order_domain',
            'order_details.custom_vps',
            'order_details.custom_hosting',
            'order_details.custom_mail',
            'order_details.bill',
            'bill'
        ]);
        
        $totalData = $model->count();
        $totalFiltered = $totalData;

        ->orWhereHas('order_detail.custom_hosting', function (&$q) {
            $q->where('is_upgrade',1);
        })
        ->orWhereHas('order_detail.custom_vps', function (&$q) {
            $q->where('is_upgrade',1);
        })
        ->orWhereHas('order_detail.custom_mail', function (&$q) {
            $q->where('is_upgrade',1);
        });
        
        $limit = ($request->length) ? $request->length : 10;
        $start = ($request->start) ? $request->start : 0;

        $model = $model->skip($start)->take($limit)->get();

        $dTable = DataTables()->of($model)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->editColumn('order_code',function($data){
                return $data->order_code;
            })
            ->editColumn('created_at',function($data){
                return date('d F Y',strtotime($data->created_at));
            })
         //blablabla....
        ->rawColumns(['status','action'])
        ->with(['recordsTotal'=>$totalData, "recordsFiltered" => $totalFiltered,'start' => $start]);

      return $dTable->make(true);
```

I was tried with **skip - take** and **offset - limit** method but still get empty rows on next page, then I debug with `dd` my code have some data already , seems like won't rendered

here is the output of my datatable
[image]

also, here is my debug output (on 2nd page):
[image]
Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: `->orWhereHas` seems to be wrongly called. Is it by mistake on the code you provided?

Comment: solved, it cause I didn't set offset, I've put the solution on answer section .. thanks for answer, anyway

Answer (score 1):

> SOLVED

I try to dynamic analyzing on yajra package, my array missing on `CollectionDataTable::paging()` on line 143 file : **yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/CollectionDataTable.php**, cause I didn't put `setOffset`

Solution :

```
$dTable = DataTables()->of($model)
            ->setOffset($start)
            ->addIndexColumn()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// make request->start  value 0 and the next page will not empty
$request->merge([
    'start' => 0,
]);

return Datatables::of($model)
    ->with([
        "recordsTotal"    => $count_total,
        "recordsFiltered" => $count_filter,
    ])
    ->addColumn('create', function ($users) {
        return date_format($users->created_at,"m-d-Y");
    })

    ->rawColumns(['create'])
    ->make(true);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).